# Move to next record recordset after query in access vba

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2007

This is my first question but I have to say that is not the first time that I've used the site. One more thing, sorry for my english...

I'm working on a project in Access 2007 with a lot of VBA code and a lot of forms to the front end. In the forms I've included record navigation buttons for the user to move between the different records of the table (next, previous, etc).

However, I have a problem I do not know how to fix. Imagine that the user enters a form. Naturally, the form shows the 1st record contained in the table. In the form, the user can search a record and go to a specified record.

After getting that record, the user presses the button to display the next record. However, instead of going to the next, it goes to the record after the 1st. In other words, the form goes to the 2nd record.

I guess it's because recordset of the form hasn't been updated, so when the user presses the next button (actually I am doing a `docmd.gotorecord acNext`), it goes to the next record that is in the table (the 2nd record).

I tried updating the recordset after making the query though the form recordsource method, but nevertheless it continues to go wrong ...

What would be the most practical solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Could you possibly explain how you're doing the search functions, do you have some code you can show us that handles it?

Comment: Hi SCB. Well, the search function is very simple. I have the primary key of the table like a not visible and, when the user select the customer that want to the see the information, the search result do this:

DoCmd.OpenForm "Customers", , , "ID=" & Me.search_customers_subform.Form.ID & ""

And the next button do this:

Me.FilterOn = False

DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext

Comment: Just posted a different comment asking for clarification but I miscounted the commas on the open form, that does make sense. Will try coming up with something for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue comes from the fact that when you set the filter to false, you actually re-set the entire form.

To get around this, you can try this for your search command:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Customers"

' This assumes that you've got a control on the customers form named ID which has the IDs in it
DoCmd.GoToControl "ID"

DoCmd.FindRecord Me.search_customers_subform.Form.ID
```

And when clicking next, all you need now is:

```
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNext
```

The filter doesn't exist anymore.

Hope this works for you. I don't have Access on me right now so this code is mainly from memory, if there's any problems, feel free to ask.